# star model in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, modeling

I need to build a report in Tableau Desktop. I am facing an issue with the modeling. The problem is that I cannot create a star schema like in Power BI, for example, because my model includes multiple calculation tables and several dimension tables. So, how can I link or connect all the calculation tables with all the dimension tables to create a table visualization where KPIs will be broken down by product?

[image]

I have built this data model in such a way that when I visualize sales by product category in a table, I get accurate figures. However, when I visualize the budget by category, I get incorrect numbers.